# zend 2 - custom field name in validation message

Tags: php, zend-framework, validation

I would like to customize input name to show in my view when happen an error in validation of the form

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'generica_descricao', // I WOULD LIKE TO CALL HIM DESCRIÇÃO
    //'custom_name' => 'Descrição',
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'NotEmpty',
            'options' => array(
                'messages' => array(
                    'isEmpty' => 'O campo não pode ser vazio'
                ),
            ),
        ),
));
```

and when i call getMessage() as the code above

```
if (!$form->isValid()) {
    $resultado = new Resultado(Resultado::FLAG_WARNING, $form->getMessages());
    $resultado->setaRetornoLayoutErro($this->getServiceLocator());
    return $resultado->getJson();
}
```

they will return

```
array('Descrição' => 'O campo não pode ser vazio');
```

then i will can give this array to my view and show dialog with the correctly messages, can anybody help how do that in zend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a best way, create a new method that extends the default form getting the name from the label in the form.

```
abstract class GenericForm extends Form {

    public function getMessagesTranslated($elementName = null) {

        $mensagensOriginais = $this->getMessages($elementName);

        foreach ($mensagensOriginais as $chave => $mensagens) {
            $label = TranslateUtil::translate($this->get($chave)->getLabel());
            $mensagensOriginais[$label] = $mensagensOriginais[$chave];
            unset($mensagensOriginais[$chave]);
        }

        return mensagensOriginais;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I customize my filter with a method that translates the field name, is not what i want but it works for now:

generic filter

```
abstract function convertErrorsArrayKeyToFriendlyNames($erros);
```

specific filter:

```
public function convertErrorsArrayKeyToFriendlyNames($erros) {

    foreach ($erros as $chave => $valor) {
        if ($chave == 'generica_descricao') {
            $erros['Descrição'] = $erros[$chave];
            unset($erros[$chave]);
        } else if ($chave == 'generica_ordem') {
            $erros['Ordem'] = $erros[$chave];
            unset($erros[$chave]);
        } else if ($chave == 'generica_ativo') {
            $erros['Ativo'] = $erros[$chave];
            unset($erros[$chave]);
        }
    }

    return $erros;
}
```

and in the controller

```
if (!$form->isValid()) {
    $erros = $filtro->convertErrorsArrayKeyToFriendlyNames($form->getMessages());
    $resultado = new Resultado(Resultado::FLAG_WARNING, $erros);
    $resultado->setaRetornoLayoutErro($this->getServiceLocator());
    return $resultado->getJson();
}
```